# Is following limit statement are True/false?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given  that $x_n  > 0$ , $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

> If $\lim_{ n\rightarrow  \infty} \sqrt [n]x_n$ exist   then  $\lim_{ n\rightarrow  \infty} \frac{ x_{n+1}}{x_n}$  also exist . True/false

My attempt : i thinks  this  statement  is true , take $ x_n = \frac{1}{n}$

Comment: No. Take $x_{2n}=1,x_{2n+1}=2$ for all $n$. (And why on earth do you think your $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$ proves anything?)

Comment: @TonyK  im sorry  that ur counterexample  didn't click in my  mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true,

Take the sequence $x_n=1$ if $n$ odd and $x_n=2$ if $n$ even.

Then denote $b_n=\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$

and we have $b_{2n}=\frac{1}{2}$ and $b_{2n+1}=2$